# Fix USB power management issues introduced with the latest update of Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, usb

We have an older USB device that is charged via the USB port and needs to be in the charge state to connect to our desktop application.
Windows 8.1 introduced Enhanced PowerManagement for USB. We were able to deal with it by setting the flag EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled = 0 in Device Parameters of the HID PID entry for our device. By using an INF file, we were able to control the configuration of new ports, when our devices are connected.
A recent update seems to have broken that:

1. The previously installed INF file info is removed on update.
2. Ports now configured do not have the flag and the device does not work.

Reinstalling the INF file corrects the issue for newly configured ports, but we are unable to fix ports already configured prior to the install. Here is what we see:

1. There is no EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled = 0 in the Device Parameter registry of the newly configured ports that do work.
2. Manually entering the parameter does not change anything - this used to work.
3. Removing the entries not working to let them reconfigure does not seem to work. Uninstalling in Device Manager (show hidden devices), killing the registry entries etc. does not seem to have an impact.

How can we fix the botched entries? Where is the updated Windows 8.1 setting the flags, when they do work?
What am I missing?
We have a bunch of very unhappy customers and I have wasted hours on this - more time than it took me to set up the original fix!
Any help would be appreciated!
-- Harald

Comment: Removing the devices with the Nirsoft USB utility (64bit version) did the trick! Interestingly, the registry entries were untouched.

Comment: I a still looking for anybody that has more info on the changes. The registry flag does not behave and look the way it used to etc.